# How to browse for folder on Windows AND OSX?

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, folderbrowserdialog

Usually, I use `SHBrowseForFolder` to support browsing for a folder... but I want to support both Windows and OSX.

I looked at:

- `System.IOUtils` but didn't find any relevant function (maybe, I missed
  one?)
- `TOpenDialog` options but didn't find one to pick a folder instead of a file...

Any idea?
(I can manage `ifdef` for Windows but I have no clue for the Mac part...)

Cheers,

W.

Comment: When you do find the answer, try not to use ifdef if you can avoid it. It's much nicer to have a single interface and make two different code files. You could name them os-support-win32 and os-support-osx, or windows-folders, osx-folders, etc. Then use the right one in the project depending on operating system. Makes the code nice to read.

Comment: Ok.. I'll try ;o) Good suggestion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [`NSOpenPanel`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class,  Jeremy North publish a sample a few weeks ago [SelectDirectory for OS X](http://jed-software.com/blog/?p=538).

Comment: It does exactly what I want... FYI, the `uses` I added:    `MacApi.AppKit, MacApi.Foundation, Macapi.CocoaTypes`

Comment: Also you can see a sample of use of this class in the `TPlatformCocoa.DialogOpenFiles` function in the FMX.Platform.Mac unit.